# Segmentation fault when implementing moving least squares method in ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to implement the moving least squares method in ROS. However, every time when I run the following code, there is a strange error saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". This occurs at line "movingLS.process(mlsPoints);". Here the code piece,

```
  void moving_least_squares_node::MovingLeastSquares::processing(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr input_msg) {
        pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> movingLS;
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal> mlsPoints;
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloudFiltered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr cloudFilteredWithNormals(
             new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);
        pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
        pcl::fromROSMsg(*input_msg, *cloud); 
        tree->setInputCloud(cloud);
        movingLS.setInputCloud(cloud);
        movingLS.setComputeNormals(true);
        movingLS.setPolynomialOrder(3);
        movingLS.setSearchMethod(tree);
        movingLS.setSearchRadius(0.06);
        // Reconstruct
        movingLS.process(mlsPoints);
        pcl::copyPointCloud(mlsPoints, *cloudFiltered);
        pcl::copyPointCloud(mlsPoints, *cloudFilteredWithNormals);
        pcl::toROSMsg(*cloudFiltered, output_msg);
        pub.publish(output_msg);
    }
```

Also, the same problem occurs in this code,

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr input_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr output_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr output_cloud_with_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);
pcl::fromROSMsg(*input_msg, *input_cloud);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>("/home/jc/hull_abstraction/prototype/point_cloud_data/16_5.pcd", *input_cloud);

pcl::ApproximateVoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> voxelGrid;
voxelGrid.setInputCloud(input_cloud);
voxelGrid.setLeafSize(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);  //Volume of voxel(AABB) is 1 cm3
voxelGrid.setDownsampleAllData(false); //No down sampling based on RGB information
voxelGrid.filter(*output_cloud);

pcl::toROSMsg(*output_cloud, output_msg);
output_msg.header.frame_id = "base";
pub.publish(output_msg);
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)

project(hull_abstraction)

find_package(PCL 1.10 REQUIRED) # find PCL library and define the required version
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    pcl_conversions
    pcl_msgs
    rospy
    sensor_msgs
    std_msgs
)


catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES hull_abstraction
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS pcl_conversions pcl_msgs roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)


include_directories(
    include 
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Load pcd flie
SET(load_pcd 
    src/load_pcd_node.cpp 
    src/load_pcd_node/load_pcd.cpp
)

add_executable(load_pcd ${load_pcd})

target_link_libraries(load_pcd
    ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

# Moving least squares method
SET(moving_least_squares 
    src/moving_least_squares_node.cpp 
    src/moving_least_squares_node/moving_least_squares.cpp
    src/hull_abstraction/functions.cpp
)

add_executable(moving_least_squares ${moving_least_squares})

target_link_libraries(moving_least_squares
    ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Any clues and suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks for every help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351185/segmentation-fault-when-implementing-moving-least-squares-method-in-ros/) by [Tachikoma](https://answers.ros.org/users/54263/tachikoma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Luckily I have solved this problem. It seems to be a incompatibility problem between PCL-1.10 and ROS-Kinetic. Everything works well after I installed and used PCL-1.8.

---

Originally posted by [Tachikoma](https://answers.ros.org/users/54263/tachikoma/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0